# React Material UI - Grid Column height property

Tags: html, css, material-ui, grid

Please refer to the picture for description. I have two div, one is 20% of total browser height, the other is should be 80%. I am using Material UI Grid for the positioning. Something looks like:

```
<Grid container direction={column}>
    <Grid item>1</Grid>
    <Grid item>2</Grid>
</Grid>
```

what should I do with the CSS in order to achive the result. I have tried to set the first grid item to height 20% and the second one to 80% but its not what I need.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the same thing you are showing in picture, insted of using `%` you could use `vh` [Viewport-percentage lengths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths). Something like:

```
<Grid container direction={"column"}>
    <Grid item className={classes.item20}>
      1
    </Grid>
    <Grid item className={classes.item80}>
      2
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The style:

```
item20: {
  height: "20vh",
},
item80: {
  height: "80vh",
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-grid-stacking-forked-33yln?file=/src/GridStacking.js) a working example.